# Convert object to float number - NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with several columns where the numbers appear as objects. I would like to convert an object with this format "[0.015158]" to a float number "0.015158"

My code is:

```
coeff_dfethapoly['Slope (b)_d1']= pd.to_numeric(coeff_dfethapoly['Slope (b)_d1'], errors = 'coerce')
```

This code does not work and the result is 'NaN'.

Comment: You might want to include a [mcve] to help people reproduce your problem. I suspect the solution is very easy, but I cannot be sure because I cannot reproduce the problem with your incomplete code. Some ideas: (1) clarify what `pd` is; (2) add `print` statements which show the values of relevant objects.